# Exception Helper factory with dynamic description

Tags: c#, exception

How do I create ExceptionHelper class that uses string templating to provide dynamic string elements to the caller of the helper?

Here is an example of how I currently do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        try
        {
            throw ExceptionHelper.CreateTechnicalException(1001);
        }
        catch (TechnicalException ex)when (ex.ErrorSeverity > Severity.Warning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.ErrorCode} {ex.Message}");
        }

        try
        {
            throw ExceptionHelper.CreateTechnicalException(2002);
        }
        catch (TechnicalException ex)when (ex.ErrorSeverity > Severity.Warning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ex.ErrorCode} {ex.Message.Replace("$id$", "1").Replace("$type$", "myType")}");
        }
    }
}

public static class ExceptionHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> TechnicalErrorDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>{{1001, "User with id $id$ does not exist"}, {1002, "Created user with id $id$"}, {2002, "User with id $id$ with type $type$ is invalid"}, {3003, "Unexpected server error"}, {4001, "Some text with $param1$ and another $param2$ included on $param3$"}};
    /// <exception cref = "KeyNotFoundException">the errorCode did not exist in dictionary</exception>
    public static TechnicalException CreateTechnicalException(int errorCode)
    {
        return new TechnicalException(errorCode, TechnicalErrorDictionary[errorCode]);
    }
}

public class TechnicalException : Exception
{
    public int ErrorCode
    {
        get;
    }

    public Severity ErrorSeverity
    {
        get;
    }

    public TechnicalException(int errorCode, string errorDescription): base (errorDescription)
    {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
        ErrorSeverity = Severity.Error;
    }
}

public enum Severity
{
    Warning,
    Error
}
```

Output is:

```
> Hello World 
> 1001 User with id $id$ does not exist 
> 2002 User with id 1
> with type myType is invalid
```

Is it possible to achive this in any better way?

I feel like the idea of having the each developer who use this Helper class, to do a string replace on parameters seems too redundant which kinda eliminates the idea of having a Helper class to encapsulate all the exception messages anyways.

I want top provide some kind of dictionary to the developers, where they can choose the exception by errorCode, and for some of the error messages parameters would be used.

dotNetFiddler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BEFS80

Comment: You could provide a dll (extra project) containing the Exception Helper.

Comment: @Malior It is not a problem to include the class or create a dll. The issue (or what I want to enhance) is how to make the Exception descriptions as they potentially could contain 1 or more parameters which should be replaced by parameters provided by the developer who use this Helper function. Sorry if I didn't explained it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those things where there isn't necessarily a 'right' way, but I can see your approach becoming a bit of a maintenance problem down the line, with all these codes everywhere....

For stuff like this I'd definitely use an Enum rather than raw int error codes - I wouldn't want to try to work out whether I'm supposed to throw a '9003' or a '9030' error.  If you really want to do things that way, use an Enum instead, and rather than trying to direct users to remember magic strings for parameters, simply create sub-classes of exception with explicit constructors:

```
public enum ExceptionCode
{
    IncorrectUser = 1001,
    InvalidPassword= 1002,
    RanOutOfBeer = 9999,
}

public enum Severity
{
    Warning,
    Error
}

public class TechnicalException : Exception
{
    public ExceptionCode ErrorCode
    {
        get;
    }

    public Severity ErrorSeverity
    {
        get;
    }

    public TechnicalException(ExceptionCode errorCode, string errorDescription) : base(errorDescription)
    {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
        ErrorSeverity = Severity.Error;
    }
}

public class InvalidUserException : TechnicalException
{
    public InvalidUserException(string username, string password) 
        : base(ExceptionCode.IncorrectUser, $"User {username} with password {password} is invalid")
    {

    }
}

public class test
{
    public void throwit()
    {
        throw new InvalidUserException("bob", "abc123");
    }
}
```

If you do this then you can still catch/list/log "TechnicalExceptions" but the code is far clearer, simpler and FAR less fragile.

Comment: I really like this approach, using enum instead of int will also make it a bit more strict, as it will only allow the subset of values in the enum, and not the entire spectrum of int. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes.  Also gives code completion etc.  I'd also suggest doing the derived exception approach rather than replacing magic strings in a dictionary;  it's not really much more code and will be so much more maintainable.  You'll be very thankful in a few years' time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this with with string format, and add the placeholder {0} {1}.. Example:

```
    public static class ExceptionHelper
    {
        private static Dictionary<int, string> TechnicalErrorDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> {{ 1001, "User with id {0} does not exist" }, { 1002, "Created user with id {0}" }, { 2002, "User with id {0} with type {1} is invalid" }, { 3003, "Unexpected server error" }, { 4001, "Some text with {0} and another {1} included on {2}" } };
        /// <exception cref = "KeyNotFoundException">the errorCode did not exist in dictionary</exception>
        public static TechnicalException CreateTechnicalException(int errorCode, params object[] para)
        {
            return new TechnicalException(errorCode, string.Format(TechnicalErrorDictionary[errorCode], para));
        }
    }
```

Only disadvantage would be, that the developer would have to exactly know the minimum required parameters for each error code, otherwise this may crash.

Comment: I wondered whether to post something like this, but I think the 'distance' between the parameters being defined (in the dictionary) vs the usage makes it rather fragile.  Would be extremely difficult to change these messages easily and get all runtime uses picked up - the same problem as OP's original solution appears to have to me)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I totally missed the string formatting, which could be a way to accomplish it. I'll try to stick with the answer that @GPW as it will provide a bit more "security" for unknown errorcodes as well.

Comment: I agree. I actually voted for your answer @GPW. It was just to solved the question doing the thing right (in contrast to yours, is doing the right thing :)  )